# How to adjust gap between columns in foundation framework?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I use Foundation framework and I want to reduce the gap between columns. Which part in foundation.css I should change to reduce gap between that 3 columns?

html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-10 columns" >
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns" >
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

hi Daniel,thanks but how about if I want adjust in specific columns? example: in 1 row, I have 2 columns, 1 column have 2 columns and the others column have 4 columns. i only want adjust the gap in this 2nd column that have 4 columns

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the paddings of the columns like this:

```css
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .column, .columns {
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

This overwrites the following default values:

```css
    padding-right: .9375rem;
    padding-left: .9375rem;
```

See https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/RvoYrr

Is is generated from the gutter mixin in https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/4abaf7ad3c508bf3fc73cb5dfd8928f756968c7d/scss/grid/_gutter.scss#L16

I have created another example with two classes `pr10` and `pl10` for adding padding to the right columns.

You can do the same on the row leel too.

https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/QYGPKO

```css
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .pl10 {
      padding-left: 10px;
      background: green;
  }
  .pr10 {
      padding-right: 10px;
      background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-10 columns" >
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">1
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">2
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">3
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns" >
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns pl10 pr10">4
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns pl10 pr10">5
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(The pr10 and pl10 is a shorthand version that is often used in CSS frameworks with utility classes like Tachyons and tailwindcss).

Or you can target the right columns with the following CSS:

```css
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .row > .medium-10.columns + .medium-2.columns > .row > .medium-6.columns {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      background: green;
  }
}
```

See https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/gqgbNG

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes, please upvote (and accept when possible) the answer.

Comment: hi Daniel,thanks but how about if I want adjust in specific columns? example: in 1 row, I have 2 columns, 1 column have 2 columns and the others column have 4 columns. i only want adjust the gap in this 2nd column that have 4 columns. i edit my main questions and code too with new questions. thanks again

Comment: You would have to add your own classes which overwrite the needed colum paddings.

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks for your help. since i have too many pages already, for now, i just think stick to the original one. thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: I have added another example which works without any changes in the DOM.

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks again for your help. if you could direct help/ point, which lines i should do on http://hotwheels26.byethost7.com/css/foundation.css the goal is to reduce gap that start on every <div class="medium-2 columns">
the medium-2 columns i want change is always on left side. i don't want change medium-2 columns if it is on right side.
http://hotwheels26.byethost7.com/2019-jan.html also how to close this question and upvote you? i just realize i can't change much if need too many pages to be amend,

Comment: Well this would nly work if you would add a custom class to the outer most different wrapper to difference them.